# Why does Chart.SetSourceData Source:=Nothing crashes Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, crash

[Chart.SetSourceData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.chart.setsourcedata) expects a Range as Source.

If there's a bug in the code and the variable that holds the Range is set to the value `Nothing` at some point it will either throw an error or crash Excel.

My question is, in the following code, why does using `Object` instead of a [`Chart`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.chart(object)) object has different behavior and why does it crash Excel?

```
Private Sub Test()

  Dim Workbook As Excel.Workbook
  Dim Worksheet As Excel.Worksheet
  Dim Shapes As Excel.Shapes
  Dim Shape As Excel.Shape

  Dim Object As Object
  Dim Chart As Excel.Chart

  Set Workbook = Excel.ThisWorkbook
  Set Worksheet = Workbook.ActiveSheet
  Set Shapes = Worksheet.Shapes
  Set Shape = Shapes.AddChart

  Set Object = Shape.Chart
  On Error Resume Next
  Object.SetSourceData Source:=Nothing ' Throws run-time error
  On Error GoTo 0

  Set Chart = Shape.Chart
  Chart.SetSourceData Source:=Nothing ' Crashes Excel regardless of using error handling or not

End Sub
```

Comment: I am not sure, but it could be because you are using `Keyword` `Object` as a name, and that's somehow confusing Excel. Same Goes with `Chart`

Comment: Another Reason is because of the Declaration you are making. Which are quite confusing as Shape is assigning a chart and Chart is being assigned `Shape.Chart`.

Comment: @Mikku The variable names aren't the issue since changing them all (for example adding "My" at the start of the name) doesn't change the behavior.

Comment: @Mikku [Shapes.AddChart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.shapes.addchart#return-value) "Returns a Shape object that represents the chart.".

Comment: Using `Object` or `Variant` results in the same by the way.